# Why don't enterprise applications use java web start?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-web-start

i just came through the java web start technology for the first time today. I am thinking that it's a great way to deploy applications using web, so that clients can use the most updated version whenever they use it.

Now my question is, why aren't enterprise applications which use javaEE are replaced with this technology? is it because the services which java application servers provide?

Comment: Web apps don't need to be updated (from the clients perspective), generally don't require additional software (ie the jre) and generally operate with in known confines (http and associated technologies), so you avoid a rafter of system issues (firewalls, system policies, etc)